# youtube api upload doesnt work

Tags: youtube-api

Im having a problem uploading a mp4 file.  It should be simple but it fails everytime.  If I manually upload it via the browser it works fine.  Using the google api following the sample fails.

```
settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(_ProductName, _DeveloperKey, _LoginName, _LoginPassword);
request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

video = new Video();



video.Title = "My Test Movie";
video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
video.Keywords = "cars, funny";
video.Description = "My description";
video.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
video.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(@"C:\MyFolder\example.mp4", "video/mp4");
videoUpload = request.Upload(video);
if (videoUpload == null)
    result = false;
else
```

it always causes the exception error:

```
Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
```

The file shows up on youtube but has the error:

```
Failed (unable to convert video file).
```

The problem is if I upload the same file manually via the browser it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this quite a big file? Have you tried this with a tiny file? I wonder if there is some kind of timeout happening.

Comment: Yes your right.  I tried it with a smaller file and it worked.  Found out that on big file you have to use a different method.  You have to use ResumableUploader

Comment: @adviner Hi I am also kind of lost in the same issue, and couldn't find much help online was wondering if you could answer few my query's : I am using the header upload method with asp.net, when you say big file, whats the MB we are talking about ? Mine is 31.3 MB file (mp4) and it fails every time, When I try uploading directly It  work but with several restart's on download on server. Any help would be appreciated.